# What gets in the way of code executing with the same duration every time?

Tags: javascript, unix, optimization, operating-system, computer-science

Say you want to benchmark the performance of different JavaScript loops, something like this: http://jsperf.com/fastest-array-loops-in-javascript/11. Or you wanted to benchmark something on the command-line with the Unix `time` command.

What, deep down in the computer, is preventing the code from executing with the exact same duration every time? By "duration" I mean, why doesn't a JavaScript `while (i--)` loop in Node.js take exactly 1.3284ms every time? Looking for the connection (a few key words or papers) between transistors and high-level programming languages.

Comment: It also depends upon the availability of resources to the OS at different times, apart from other factors

Comment: My question is along the lines of that, what are these `resources` and how do they work? How do I include them in benchmarking calculations, so I can remove them from the equation?

Comment: I guess it's about scheduling in a multi-task environment. There are factors like cache hits/misses which IMO can differ from execution to execution. If you completely want to eliminate those factors you would have to run your application without a Multi-Task-OS.

Answer (score 2):

The measurement isn't precise in the first place, because of time resolution. See [times](http://linux.die.net/man/2/times), for example.

If there are lots of processes running, you will get a different wall clock time than with only a few processes competing for CPU time.

Cache misses, swapping will also interfere, causing different overall time from one run to the other.

If you read files from disk, the allocation of the file's blocks will also have an impact on the time spent reading or writing a file.

Comment: The "lost" time is called context switching in computing. It is the time needed by the operating system to switch context when executing little bits of different processes after one another. Each processes' CPU time will only be increased by the time spent actually _executing_ a given process. The time needed to switch to another process will still count towards any time measurements done on the code level.